# Using class method as default kwarg argument?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, keyword-argument

This is a super contrived example, but I have been wanting to assign the default value for a kwarg argument to the return value of a class method.

```
class Robot():
    def get_name(self):
        return 'Bob'

    def speak(self, name=self.get_name()):
        print('hello, my name is {name}.'.format(name=name))

r = Robot()
r.speak()

>>> NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I was able to do this long-hand by defaulting to None adn then adding some conditional logic later on.

```
class Robot():
    def get_name(self):
        return 'Bob'

    def speak(self, name=None):
        if not name:
            name = self.get_name()
        print('hello, my name is {name}.'.format(name=name))

r = Robot()
r.speak()

>>>hello, my name is Bob.
```

But what I would like is to remove the need for the conditional logic in the function. Can I achieve the same thing with a lambda as a default for the kwarg? This is what I have tried so far:

```
class Robot():
    def get_name(self):
        return 'Bob'

    def speak(self, name=lambda name: self.get_name()):
        print('hello, my name is {name}.'.format(name=name))

r = Robot()
r.speak()

>>>hello, my name is <function Robot.<lambda> at 0x103a4f5f0>.
```

Comment: I think using `None` is the common way to do what you want. Anything else would likely be confusing to anyone trying to understand the code.

Comment: yeah, you are probably right. was curious nonetheless.